# I can't find my Spring boot httpOnly Cookie on my client site

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot *2.3.1.RELEASE* and trying to send a *httpOnly Cookie* to the client.
The problem is Chrome isn't showing any Cookies.
[image]
Same situation with Postman.
[image]
One thing is that in the Postman response log, I can see the header `Set-Cookie` with its value, while on Chrome, `console.log(res.headers);` gives `undefined`
[image]
Here's my server code

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> sendCookie(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) {

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", "one_cookie_for_you");

    cookie.setMaxAge(7 * 24 * 60 * 60); // expires in 7 days
    cookie.setSecure(true);
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);

    response.addCookie(cookie);

    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no host/url the cookie is attached to, (at least that is what it looks like). Also accessing the cookie by javascript won't be possible because it is HttpOnly (which is the whole point of the HttpOnly flag).

Comment: Thank you. That helped me solve the problem. I'll give the answer based on your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *@M. Deinum* I've been able to solve the problem, turns out it was my lack of knowledge. Thank you again, here's the solution.

Since my client is on *localhost* which is *non-https*, the cookie's *secured* flag must be set to `false` like `cookie.setSecure(false);` so that the browser will store the cookie even if the protocol is not secured.

Secondly, my code was missing `cookie.setPath("");` and `cookie.setDomain("")` which makes Spring automatically set the cookie's path to the api's mapping. Setting it's *domain name* and path to `"/"` makes the cookie sent in any requests.